# Windows Batch Files: copy sequential files

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, sequential

Just a quick foreword: I'm an artist, and only have a small amount of programming understanding, and I just started learning windows batch files a couple hours ago.

So, at my school, when we render our files in Maya, we have to do it on a local drive, and we use several computers to speed up this process.
This creates hundreds of images across multiple computers.
My plan was to create a batch file that copies the images (as they are finished) over the network to a single drive so managing my rendered images is easier.

I'm using a for loop to go through file names (in this case, BallTest_xxxx.exr), and I can print out the name just fine; but, when I try setting the filename to a variable in the loop, it ends up printing out nothing.

Where I have "echo.%asdf%, I want that to be where it reads the file, and from there, checks to see if the render is finished (I have a couple of ideas for the latter, but for now, I'd just like some insight on what I'd need to do to make the first part work.)
I can see in the results, that when I try to set asdf as the filename, it gives me BallTest_000%x.exr, which I know isn't right.

```
set "filename=BallTest_"
set "extension=.exr"

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 3) do (
    if %%x lss 10 (
        set asdf=%filename%000%%x%extension%
        echo.%filename%000%%x%extension%
        echo.%asdf%
    )
)

pause
```

Thanks in advance,

George

Comment: Have you tried **set asdf=%filename%"000"%%x%extension%** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be this is what you are looking for:

```
@echo off
set "filename=BallTest_"
set "extension=.exr"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 3) do (
    if %%x lss 10 (
        set asdf=%filename%000%%x%extension%
        echo.%filename%000%%x%extension%
        echo.!asdf!
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

Delayed expansion is a confusing thing for newbies in batch files.
More info you can find [here](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)  and [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php)

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me.
After seeing the comment before your answer, I sat back down and tried to figure it out.

I eventually found out how to make it work, and it turns out it was exactly what you suggested.
I'm certain that how I made the entire thing come together is not the most clean or optimal way of doing it (dealing with frame padding of up to 4 digits ended up looking ugly and clunky) but it works now, and my renders go straight to the proper drive.

Answer (score 0):

This builds on the answer by npocmaka:

The `REM` lines are just batch file comments, included to assist understanding. Feel free to remove them in your final code.

```
@echo off

REM Set the part of the filename before the number padded with zeroes
set "filename=DocumentPrefix"

REM Set the remaining part of the filename after the number padded with zeroes
set "extension=Suffix.txt"

REM Enable delayed expansion so variables are expanded at execution time rather than parse time
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

REM Give the variable %%x a range of values
for /l %%x in (2, 1, 4) do (

    REM Pad the current number with zeros (lots used here to account for possible numbers reaching high orders)
    set "paddedNumber=00000000%%x"

    REM Extract the padded number with the desired number of digits
    set "paddedNumber=!paddedNumber:~-6!

    REM Tell the user what file is being copied (or moved)
    echo Copying %filename%!paddedNumber!%extension%

    REM Replace "copy" with "move" to move files rather than copy
    REM Replace the source and destination addresses with your own
    copy "C:\Path\To\Source\Folder\%filename%!paddedNumber!%extension%" "C:\Path\To\Destination\Folder\"
    )
)

endlocal

REM Pause the script at the end so the user can see that the batch file has stopped (and hopefully completed correctly)
pause
```

If you want to move the files rather than copy, simply change the `copy` (at the end of the for loop to `move`.

To only copy a selection of files, change the three numbers in the for loop as you see fit. The for loop numbers correspond to (first number, interval, last number). For example, for padded sequential files like `0003`, `0004`, to copy files `6` to `15` from the folder, change the for loop numbers to be `(6,1,15)`. If you only want to copy/move every nth file, specify `(1,n,x)`, where `n` is the interval (e.g. 3 for every third file) and `x` is the number of the last file you want to copy (ideally it should be some multiple of `n` plus 1).

I set `paddedNumber` to have eight zeros. You won't need to adjust this line unless your folder has more than 100 million files.